# Debugging Easeljs or kineticjs.js

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, easeljs

Many javascript libraries, like easeljs or kinetic.js are available as

- source code
- minified built version

When I make take a first look at them, I do not want minified versions, but debuggable normal versions.

**Anybody has a fast way to debug these 2 libraries?**

I tried to build easeljs without minification but I am not to familiar with Closure, and I do not see a way to stop it from minifying, as I understand it always bundles and minifies.

I will not include the many source files in the right order to get this done.

To the Library Maintainers: Thank you, but *please* ship non minified versions and place a link to them on top of the ReadMe.

**EDIT**
Found a non minified version for kinetic:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.2-beta.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can imagine, the “source” for these libraries are packaged into javascript modules—not one big source file.

You can view the KineticJS dependencies here: http://kineticjs.com/configurator.php

You can view the EaselJS build manifest here: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/build/config.json

Then just put the appropriate source files in a folder along with your html/css files.  Be sure to script-reference all the source files in your html file.

From there, use your browser’s inspector or your favorite programming IDE.

You're golden(!) -- your debugger will reference the appropriate source file + offending line#!

Comment: Hmmm including all sources, just what I wanted to avoid. Anyway, copying from config.json is a good idea, it should work. In the end there might not be another way around including all source parts. I consider it a very bad habit to deliver minified only, would much expect "1 normal js file" per library. Found one for kinetic and kicked easel therefore. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: The EaselJS build process includes an unminified flag, which just bundles the source together. Check out the readme (see the part on pretty printing) https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/build/README.textile